# DataBindingComponent is null, bind(view) must not be null with DataBinding at FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:332)

Tags: android, android-layout, data-binding, android-databinding

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ProfileFragmentBinding.bind(view) must not be null
    at com.xx.profile.ProfileFragment.onViewCreated(ProfileFragment.kt:39)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:332)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1187)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2224)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1997)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1953)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1849)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run(FragmentManager.java:413)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:198)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7055)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:523)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:836)
```

From the last few days i am getting a very weird exception and the crash is happening mainly because of DataBindingComponent, as it is returning null, with dataBinding

It's working good with ViewBinding but with databinding it's crashing

Note(Coincidently): I have 21 modules in my project including this, i got this exception at runtime for every databinding module, and if i remove any other module and make it to 20, the code excecute fine for both databinding as well as for viewbinding.

But i need this as Module, It will be great, if u guys could assist me. Thanks in advance.

I am using Navigation-Architecture component with BottomNavigationView.

My Code is as Follows,

```
package com.xx.profile

import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.lifecycle.observe
import com.xx.core.dagger.ViewModelFactory
import com.xx.core.dagger.coreComponent
import com.xx.core.util.LogoutInterface
import com.xx.core.util.context.launchUrl
import com.xx.core.util.event.EventObserver
import com.xx.profile.databinding.ProfileFragmentBinding
import com.xx.profile.di.DaggerProfileComponent
import javax.inject.Inject

class ProfileFragment(private val logoutInterface: LogoutInterface) : Fragment(R.layout.profile_fragment) {

private lateinit var binding: ProfileFragmentBinding

@Inject
lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelFactory

private val viewModel: ProfileViewModal by lazy {
    ViewModelProvider(viewModelStore, viewModelFactory).get(ProfileViewModal::class.java)
}

override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    DaggerProfileComponent.factory().create(context.coreComponent()).inject(this)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    binding = ProfileFragmentBinding.bind(view)

}
```

}

My xml is as follows,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    tools:context=".ProfileFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp"
        tools:ignore="ExtraText">


    </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>
</layout>
```

Comment: If you're using DataBinding, where is your `<layout>` in your XML?

Comment: @ianhanniballake, apology for it, i had already added the tag in xml code above, but due to formatting issue, it was not appearing.

Comment: It was due to  duplicates of package names in multi modules project.